# Is it ok to take a new car on a road trip?

Tags: car

I have a new car with about 500 miles on it, breakin is 1000 miles.  Is it ok to take it on a 1200 mile road trip?  600 each way?

Answer (score 2):

A 100 years ago it made a difference, not so much today. The owner's manual will probably have something like "not over 75 MPH in the first 1000 miles". I may be wrong ; Looking in my 2011 Nissan Murano manuals ,it only says "change oil  at 7500 miles".

Comment: I just bought new and the break in instructions said to drive it normal except to avoid fast eccellerations and do not drive constant speeds on the highway.

Comment: Your owner's manual is your friend here.  While there are many and differing opinions on break-in or not.  You should ALWAYS follow the manufacturer's advice in order to protect your warranty.  If there is some limit during the first "X" miles, then follow that.  If not, then drive as you would any car, within reason of course.

Answer (score 1):

New cars are made tough and efficient nowadays. 1200 miles should be piece of cake. Usual first change oil is 1500-2000 miles or according to the manufacturer. My buddy got a new Wrangler and we install a set of mud tires from 4Wheelonline and took it for 5 days 2000 miles road and off-road journey without any issue, both on low and high speed.